# Como mover la consola de carpeta (bash)

Tags: bash

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy intentando en bash hacer que cuando se ejecute mi archivo, mueva al usario de carpeta incluso en la consola, para darme a entender mejor este es mi archivo bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test "cd /var/www/html"; then
    echo "Ok"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
```

Y me gustaria que si por ejemplo ejecuto ese archivo en el directorio home, por ejemplo si hago este comando:

```
ejemplo@ejemplo:~$ ./file.sh
```

El resultado sea este:

```
ejemplo@ejemplo:/var/www/html$
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto mi archivo solo me muestra `OK` pero sigue sin moverme de directorio, espero me puedan ayudar con mi problema. Desde ya gracias :).

Comment: ¿Seguro?  Luego lo he probado en mi sistema y no ha funcionado. Ahora estaba mirando otra forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deberías reescribir tu script a esto:

```sh
DIRECTORY=/var/www/html
if [[ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]]
then
   cd "$DIRECTORY"
   echo "Ok"
else
   echo "Error"
fi
```

Y luego ejecutarlo mediante `source file.sh`

Explicación:

- Primero verificamos que el directorio exista mediante

  ```sh
  if [[ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]]
  ```
- Y si existe nos movemos a él mediante

  ```sh
  cd "$DIRECTORY"
  ```
- En caso contrario devuelve `Error`

  Y debe ejecutarse con:

  ```sh
  source file.sh
  ```

  para que actue sobre la shell actual.

  También puede usarse el `punto` (**dot**) incluído en las normas [POSIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) de este modo:

  ```sh
  . file.sh
  ```

  que es idéntico comportamiento. En este enlace describen y explican la sintaxis del `.`: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot

Es decir, cuando ejecutas el programa de la forma `$ ./programa`, se abre un subproceso dependiente del de tu consola, que es diferente al de tu consola. Entonces, todo lo que ocurra en ese ambiente, no tendría porque alterar las variables de proceso padre.

En cambio, cuando usas `. programa`, o `source programa`, el script se va a cargar directamente en tu consola, como si lo estuvieras escribiendo tú.

Por esto es que si le indicas a un subproceso que haga un `cd`, el subproceso "cambiara" de dirección, pero al terminar, no le habrá pasado nada al proceso padre, es decir, a tu consola, y tu seguirás en la misma ruta.

Comment: Lo intente tanto de esta forma como de la pasada y ambas funcionaron, solo que en la otra tuve que dejar el `cd` directo sin `if` ni nada porque si no no funcionaba, pero de esta forma también funcionó, por lo que mejor voy a usar esta forma, muchas gracias :).

Comment: @masterguru, por si ayuda a completar la respuesta, la manera que dices que no te funciona `./file.sh` es porque para el caso de que se ejecute en la shell actual sería `. file.sh`

Comment: @msalinas Muchas gracias, Ya me parecia a mi raro. Justo lo habia leido antes de responder y pensé que se referia a `./` en lugar de esta otra notación que dices, y no entendia porque no me funcionaba. Eso me pasa por leerme las cosas en diagonal :-)  Voy a actualizar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el directorio del bash sigue siendo el mismo, aunque el proceso se ejecute en otro. Sin embargo, puedes añadir al final 'exec bash' para salir del script en el directorio que desees. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
ruta=$(dialog --title "Selecciona un directorio" \
          --stdout \
      --dselect ~/. 14 70)
cd ${ruta}
clear
echo "Directorio seleccionado: ${ruta}"
exec bash
```

Este script de linux te llevará la consola a la carpeta que quieras. Pero cuando vayas a cerrar la terminal, cierra también el proceso 'exec bash' mediante 'exit'.
Un saludo.

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue respondida hace 2 años, y el autor aceptó la respuesta por válida. Evita reflotar preguntas antiguas si ya fueron solucionadas. Veo que eres un usuario nuevo, echa un ojo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @PabloGonzález vuelvo a mencionar: en [es.so] no existe el concepto de _necrobumping_, por lo tanto es válido responder a preguntas antiguas que incluso cuenten con respuestas aceptadas. Una respuesta _aceptada_ significa que la respuesta le ha sido útil a OP, no necesariamente que es la única respuesta válida a tal pregunta. Lo que sí debe hacer el autor de esta respuesta es pulsar en [edit] y explicar qué hace su código, en base a [answer].